# Как пишется

Tags: морфология

Все подобные слова - как правильно писать? Через пробел, тире или слитно?
(Около)домовая территория или (около)телевизионная тема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: околодомовая территория, околотелевизионная тема. Здесь ОКОЛО является приставкой.

У Ожегова: ОКОЛО - приставка. Образует   существительные  и прилагательные со  знач.  нахождения рядом, поблизости,  напр.   околоцветник,   околозвездный,  околоземный,  околопланетный,  окололунный, околоосевой.